# LocalStorage not clearing when changing to incoginto or private window

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I've seen in most of the websites the session is lost when we switch from simple window to `incoginto window` or a `private window` the user need to login again but I'm storing user access token in `localStorage` which doesn't seem to empty on shifting to private window.

So my question is what can be substitute for this situation.

> A little explanation to the question:The user logs in simple window
>   then open same website in incoginto window and is still logged in.

Comment: You sure you closed all old incognito windows before testing? localStorage should afaik never pass on to incognito. Otherwise there is its little brother `sessionStorage` or you can still create cookies using JavaScript

Comment: Yeah I think the window was open already but it shouldn't have logged in the private window